# How do I automate sorting/aligning multiple data sets in Excel by NEARLY common values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, alignment

I would like to align multiple (6+) data sets (each 3 columns x 1000 rows) by a common variable('mass' column) where each set will have a couple of exactly matching common values, numerous nearly-matching common values (ie 635.62417 & 635.62413), and numerous unique values. But I need to align all 6 sets according to the nearly matching values and maintain each of their adjacent (related) columns, including unique values.

For example, with just 3 sets and only 2 columns per set, it might look like this:

[image: massSets]

Since I need to align the sets by common (mass) and nearly common values (provided they match within 0.0005%) while maintaining each set's adjacent info columns (count) AND non-matching values... So it would look like:

[image: massSetsAligned]

As I mentioned I need to align 6 related 3 column datasets, and then repeat ~100 times. So the less manual sorts/clicks, the better.

I have tried Vlookup but it only returns the common column and doesnt support more than two data sets (as far as I am aware). It also requires creation of matching columns, which gets unwieldy when aligning across 6 (3-column) sets.

I also tried creating a dataset label column (setA, setB, setC..) for every row of every set, and then concatenating all 6+sets into one 6000+ value  (now 4) column set, sorting by common variable column (mass) and then writing a nested-if function to search for 6 nearly consecutive values with all 6 set labels (a,b,c...). However, the function got to be too long, and it couldn't handle it if one set contained more than one value in the nearly-the-same interval (0.0005%) before the 6th set's value. For example all 6 sets might have nearly common values (within the 0.0005% interval), but one or more set(s) had two values within the interval, creating 7 or more consecutive values within the interval of the concatenated sorted list.

Keeping the uniques, and maintaining the sequence (order) of the common variable column is important, but I might find some work-arounds once I know I can align.

Here is a (csv list) more full/exact data set (first 14 rows) to play with.

```
massA,countA,relA,massB,countB,relB,massC,countC,relC,massD,countD,relD,massE,countE,relE,massF,countF,relF
326.76558,663172.1,23,326.76561,863181.6,33.2,326.76554,2076507.5,33,326.76539,628073.8,32.18,326.76536,165294.3,32.73,326.76551,479780.8,31.48
327.76889,36016.5,1,327.76898,51965.1,2,327.76898,111976.8,2,327.76887,43550.3,2.23,327.76885,8935.5,1.77,327.76891,26583.1,1.74
328.76345,2002753.8,70,328.76352,2600265,100,328.76341,6305402,100,328.76329,1951801.5,100,328.76324,505034.4,100,328.76342,1459376.4,95.75
328.80699,2006.8,0,328.80427,2832.7,0.11,328.80594,21364.6,0,328.80591,1931.2,0.1,328.80597,378.7758,0.075,328.80603,773.5,0.05
328.7224,5367,0,328.72241,3207.2,0.12,328.72382,14715.6,0,328.72274,2441.8,0.13,328.72091,545.4,0.11,328.72237,1335.1,0.09
329.76683,118114,4,329.76693,159077.5,6.12,329.76682,368688.9,6,329.76664,111203.6,5.7,329.76665,27753.8,5.5,329.76683,85531.4,5.61
330.72018,4853.3,0,330.71986,2861.8,0.11,330.7215,14641.9,0,330.72029,3691.3,0.19,330.71862,577.2,0.11,330.71974,960.7,0.06
330.76132,1931960,68,330.76148,2597397.8,99.89,330.7613,6159470,98,330.7612,1948729.3,99.84,330.76119,491752.1,97.37,330.76136,1414513.4,92.81
330.80504,3261.9,0,330.80228,3143.2,0.12,330.80403,22439,0,330.80453,1986.6,0.1,330.80216,425.6,0.08,330.803345,1371.68667,0.09
331.76471,117533.1,4,331.76486,154505,5.94,331.7647,380896.9,6,331.7645,112448.4,5.76,331.76449,30269.2,5.99,331.76478,84866.9,5.57
332.75928,629556.9,22,332.75945,822702.6,31.64,332.75922,2007981.4,32,332.75916,616306.8,31.58,332.75917,157364.1,31.16,332.75937,447454.4,29.36
333.76267,35806.1,1,333.76281,45357.7,1.74,333.76243,123755.1,2,333.76256,36081.1,1.85,333.76247,8091.5,1.6,333.76269,24453.3,1.6
263.8424,74600.3,3,263.84242,95206.3,3.66,263.84234,200139.7,3,263.8422,100043.6,5.13,263.84221,27144.5,5.37,263.8423,57418,3.77
264.84988,3041.4,0,264.85007,2333.9,0.09,264.85021,7924.4,0,264.84999,7981.5,0.41,264.85002,1653,0.33,264.85026,559.3,0.04
265.8403,163586,6,265.84033,188887.3,7.26,265.84026,395184.9,6,265.84017,207591.2,10.64,265.8401,53300.3,10.55,265.84023,116756.2,7.66
266.84807,9515.3,0,266.84807,5249,0.2,266.84808,16061.4,0,266.84791,15974.4,0.82,266.84806,5303,1.05,266.84793,2493,0.16
266.84358,7025.1,0,266.84365,5586.2,0.21,266.8435,14268.8,0,266.84354,8026.3,0.41,266.84353,1134.2,0.22,266.84374,2020.3,0.13
267.83825,84599.6,3,267.83832,93845,3.61,267.83829,201742.9,3,267.83818,96077.6,4.92,267.83811,26448.1,5.24,267.83824,57441.8,3.77
268.84606,3934.6,0,268.84583,661,0.03,268.8461,2339.6,0,268.84588,7800,0.4,268.84604,926.6,0.18,268.84596,4419.87927,0.29
157.83689,16810.5,1,157.83697,29968.8,1.15,157.83692,70280.5,1,157.83686,34059.8,1.75,157.83686,14758.6,2.92,157.83689,28073.5,1.84
159.83488,39914,1,159.83494,70214.1,2.7,159.83491,151654.6,2,159.83485,66569.3,3.41,159.83482,32353.1,6.41,159.83488,56339.1,3.7
161.83287,20761,1,161.83294,31342.9,1.21,161.83289,73400.1,1,161.83287,38196.6,1.96,161.83281,16197.7,3.21,161.83288,25000.1,1.64
163.00345,220063.8,8,163.00347,237746.2,9.14,163.00289,30727.4,0,163.00342,57646.9,2.95,163.00337,22231.9,4.4,163.00338,119727.8,7.86
635.62323,12595.4,0,635.62417,25581.9,0.98,635.62436,58651.6,1,635.62413,17395.4,0.89,635.62372,4100,0.81,635.62393,11804.6,0.77
637.6217,37648.4,1,637.62228,52332.3,2.01,637.62194,134509.9,2,637.622,35374.4,1.81,637.62149,8803.7,1.74,637.62174,25582.2,1.68
638.62532,4504.4,0,638.62727,4862.1,0.19,638.62582,10196.8,0,638.62539,4313.6,0.22,638.62519,981.7,0.19,638.62614,948.8,0.06
639.61961,33439.9,1,639.62008,54038.1,2.08,639.61973,149375.4,2,639.61962,32844.5,1.68,639.6199,9213.8,1.82,639.62018,20927,1.37
640.62407,3861.6,0,640.62419,4089.7,0.16,640.62423,7218.1,0,640.62452,4605.5,0.24,640.62324,958.6,0.19,640.62433,1228.2,0.08
641.6175,14621.9,1,641.61778,24032.5,0.92,641.61728,55983.9,1,641.61733,16440.4,0.84,641.61719,3941.8,0.78,641.61691,7661.2,0.5
643.61397,757.5,0,643.61594,660.3,0.03,643.6151,16674.9,0,643.61623,702.9,0.04,643.61483,349.2,0.07,643.61553,838.252965,0.055
172.92396,17893.7,1,172.92408,40444.7,1.56,172.92399,87332.7,1,172.92395,21944.1,1.12,172.92396,9251.5,1.83,172.92399,20715.7,1.36
174.92203,21998.3,1,174.92207,42146.2,1.62,174.92201,84257.5,1,174.9219,22169.3,1.14,174.92192,8113.8,1.61,174.92197,20103.8,1.32
248.85526,10542.4,0,248.85531,6942.9,0.27,248.85513,32681.2,1,248.85514,6172.5,0.32,248.85512,1150,0.23,248.85526,2262.7,0.15
250.8532,27379.1,1,250.85336,17658.1,0.68,250.85317,82113.1,1,250.8532,16332.8,0.84,250.85326,2843.4,0.56,250.85325,10750.2,0.71
252.85109,7609.2,0,252.85126,5865.8,0.23,252.85123,39003.5,1,252.8511,7526.8,0.39,252.85116,880.6,0.17,252.85129,2579.4,0.17
200.91899,22578.7,1,200.91915,23582.9,0.91,200.91904,48033.5,1,200.91899,45159.5,2.31,200.91896,13365.7,2.65,200.91895,18057,1.18
202.91704,22374,1,202.91711,29167.1,1.12,202.91693,37637.1,1,202.91696,37763,1.93,202.91693,11590.6,2.3,202.91692,17850.4,1.17
654.62475,6218.2,0,654.62474,6263.9,0.24,654.62512,34917.9,1,654.62424,8703.6,0.45,654.62395,2130.8,0.42,654.62476,1277.4,0.08
656.62088,4013.7,0,656.62272,6325,0.24,656.62196,27173.5,0,656.62202,6672.7,0.34,656.62218,1515.7,0.3,656.62318,2887.1,0.19
292.86374,6998.5,0,292.86376,4749.7,0.18,292.86362,29654.4,0,292.86364,19746.4,1.01,292.86354,3251.2,0.64,292.86373,1184.8,0.08
290.86581,914.2,0,290.86575,1732.3,0.07,290.86556,6614.1,0,290.86553,7055.4,0.36,290.86553,976.2,0.19,290.86553,4191.264825,0.275
294.86156,1370.1,0,294.86207,1303.6,0.05,294.86127,6421.9,0,294.86132,4964.6,0.25,294.86109,577.4,0.11,294.861205,2743.37334,0.18
574.6986,6112.1,0,574.69877,5215.9,0.2,574.6982,25223.8,0,574.69846,8328.1,0.43,165.01896,305437.5,60.48,111.94696,1524096.3,100
576.6961,2803.3,0,576.69681,1871.3,0.07,576.69614,20312.2,0,165.019,747884.1,38.32,111.94696,282547.7,55.95,121.02922,1136269.3,74.55
572.70044,1272.1,0,572.70022,2960.5,0.11,572.70012,18267.1,0,116.9283,501429.7,25.69,116.92828,136035.1,26.94,116.92829,570097.6,37.41
280.82724,11677.6,0,280.82731,13248,0.51,280.82727,21424.3,0,111.94697,387397.6,19.85,96.95965,74242.5,14.7,96.95965,405330.9,26.59
282.82526,3499.7,0,282.84307,4110,0.16,282.82486,10716.8,0,121.02922,187257.4,9.59,121.02924,72262.8,14.31,95.95182,400722.9,26.29
588.69475,1473.4,0,588.69537,1128.8,0.04,588.69539,13532,0,96.95966,161074.3,8.25,95.95183,68601.8,13.58,165.01897,319093,20.94
592.69121,1036.3,0,592.69156,2098,0.08,592.6909,12939.6,0,157.12306,148161.1,7.59,89.02388,62551.8,12.39,137.02409,302347.7,19.84
590.69251,1597.3,0,590.69326,4618.1,0.18,590.6928,7383.8,0,132.9232,139855.3,7.17,108.04254,59873.6,11.86,131.91534,151858.3,9.96
137.02415,479309.5,17,268.84583,661,0.03,268.8461,2339.6,0,137.02412,124271.5,6.37,132.92318,44051.6,8.72,139.0034,149355.3,9.8
121.0293,1803139.5,63,268.84197,1134.3,0.04,268.84176,5871.5,0,89.02389,118919.7,6.09,137.0241,41236.9,8.17,132.92315,138549.3,9.09
108.0426,68503.5,2,111.94702,2107023.5,81.03,137.02345,20754.6,0,143.10743,117970.8,6.04,157.12304,40907.6,8.1,153.01903,136329.7,8.94
```

Comment: can you please post also data in an editable format so that we can play around with it? What similar means for you, only difference in last two digits? Is it a number like data, so you look for similar values, or also e.g. only first digit difference makes them similar? Is your data stored as number or text. Also would be good the real size of the data, we may give you a solution which works nice for two column datasets, but too complicated for bigger ones. ...

Comment: Similar means common variable values (mass) within 0.0005% of each other. Data stored as numbers. Will csv data list work for you? (see edit).

Comment: yes, that's perfect

Comment: doesn't sound to be a typical Excel task, are you open for a solution in e.g. Microsoft Access?

Comment: I guess so. I was hoping to avoid that as my excel familiarity far exceeds access comfort.

Comment: You're doing multiple matches.  Value A could be within the error limit compared to Value B;  Value B could be within the error limit compared to Value C, but Value A vs. Value C might not be within the limit.  One solution would be to pre-scan all of the values you will be matching on and use the rules required to create a table of nominal, standard values.  Create a new dataset where you replace the actual non-matching values with the standardized values.  It will then be a clean task to do what you want.